# How to get data back when you launch the URL in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, callback, response, flutter-web, url-launcher

I've one slack URL which I am opening using URL launched and in that URL I need to login to slack and after that, it gives me some JSON response that response I want back in the app. I've tried some solutions but it didn't work.

The URL will return me JSON data
PS : I am using Flutter web so i want it to be worked in Web

Comment: As you have tried some solution, can you please post the code.

Comment: Just tried something with html.open etc and then webview but webview is only supported for apps not for webs

Comment: Have you tried [webviewx](https://pub.dev/packages/webviewx)?

Comment: Yes but webview is only works for apps not for Flutter Web

Comment: It works. Flutter Web with WebView working.

Comment: can you send me that  webview package link which can work with webview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245790/discussion-between-pratik-butani-and-rutvik-gumasana).